# Orgmode link description without https

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, org-link

I would like to have a capture template that would take a pasted link like:

`https://orgmode.org/manual/Completion.html`

and return:

`[https://orgmode.org/manual/Completion.html][orgmode.org/manual/Completion.html]`

My goal is to have a shorter, cleaner description. Even better would be to have it strip the extension from the description as well.

I have seen %(EXP) in the manual but my elisp is novice (purely used for my config files). This my current capture template:

```
("c" "paste clipboard" entry
 (file "~/Dropbox/inbox.txt")
 "* PROC %c%?" :prepend t)))
```

Comment: You can use `%(EXP)` (Evaluate Elisp expression EXP and replace it with the result.)  to get the style you want. see https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion

Comment: Do you have a capture already that does *not* do the transformation? If so, add it to your question. The transformation itself should be easy.

Comment: By the way, another way to have better descriptions is to have page titles together with the links. Personally I use two methods for this: first, a plugin in the browser for org-capture, which invokes it through org-protocol and passes the title and the address. Second, a plugin that copies both the title and the address to the clipboard, so I paste them anywhere I like. The latter kind of plugins often have customizable templates, so you can have Org-style links ready in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add something like this:

```lisp
("l" "Insert a link with a cleaned-up description" entry (file "~/Dropbox/inbox.txt")
 "* [[%c][%(replace-regexp-in-string \"^https?://\" \"\" (replace-regexp-in-string \"\\.[a-z0-9]+$\" \"\" \"%c\"))]]"
 :prepend t)
```

This removes both the protocol and the extension. However, while that should work via just one regex, for some reason org-capture's processing hiccups when it sees a pipe in the regex, and doesn't perform the replacement. So instead I have to call `replace-regexp-in-string` twice.

Note that all those backslashes are necessary, including the double one.

Also, removing extensions can be messy: considering that the web doesn't impose any requirements for extensions to be there, people are free to use all kinds of addresses, including ones with a dot and some word at the end. E.g. Wikipedia's page of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com. These will be stripped from the description by the brute approach. Perhaps you'll want to remove just some known extensions—for that, replace `[a-z0-9]+` in the second regex with something like `\(html\|php\|cfm\)` etc. Again, the backslashes need to be there. To switch off the removal of extensions altogether, replace the second `(replace-regexp-in-string ...)` with just `\"%c\"`.

Comment: Capture templates are confusing enough as it is: they don't need the additional confusion that regexps introduce. IMO, it would be better to define a function that does the transformation (and encapsulates the regexps),  and then just call the function in the template. Also, can you explain the difference between `%c` as the OP had it and `%:link` as you have it?

Comment: @NickD you were right about the `c`↔`link` discrepancy: I fell back into the habits of dealing with `org-protocol`, forgetting that the OP has  links coming from a different source. Thanks! As for a function,  IMO that would be overkill just for the regexes—though dispensing with some backslashes would be nice. However, it might make sense if I add the ability to switch off the replacement of extensions or to customize it, as suggested by my edit. I'll think a bit later of how to better organize that.

Comment: After adding %c that worked. Thanks so much!